# How to get codelyzer 2.0.0-beta.2 to work with ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

The current ionic (v2.1.0) pins Angular@2.2.1. This is fine with Codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.1

Meanwhile, Codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.2 officially provides feature supporting Ionic 2 page components. But pins Angular@^2.3.1

Is there anyone has ever made them working together?

Comment: what else besides npm warnings do you get? Any errors?

Comment: I do have some errors after updating to 2.0.0, but they are thrown by browser in karma tests. These don't seem like related, but I haven't changed any code or config. Just upgraded codelyzer.